Ensuring Consistent Sentiment Analysis Responses with Mistral-Nemo via Ollama
I am using mistral-nemo through ollama for sentiment analysis . For the same input text , I am getting different responses . I have tried setting the temperature= 0  but still it gives different answer all the time for the same input text. Is there any way that for the same text , asked multiple times gives consistent response to it ?
